# Text input focus issue on Windows Phone (Universal) with Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I'm currently building a mobile app using Cordova platform. The app was targeted on Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8. Recently, I had to change the latter to Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal). After adding the [winstore-jscompat library](https://github.com/MsopenTech/winstore-jscompat) and making couple changes to CSS everything seems to work the same way.

Only thing that is not working is scrolling to focused element. 
In Windows Phone 8 it looks like this:

Before WP8 (Ignore the darker rectangle on the bottom)

[image: Before WP8]

And After WP8

[image: After WP8]

But on Windows Phone Universal the view is not going up to fit to the screen and the cursor is in weird place.

Before WP8.1 (Universal)

[image: Before WP8.1]

And After WP8.1 (Universal). You can see cursor in the place marked by a red arrow.
[image: After WP8.1]

I'm using Cordova Tools in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 (14.0.22609.0). Using built project from /bld directory gives the same results.

Has anyone came across such bug? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share a simple repro project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Cordova to version 5.0.0 resolved this problem.

[image: Cordova Windows Phone input]